# Remove html markup from string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex

I am reading in a field from the database and displaying in a GridView and in that field it contains `<br/>` tags in the text. So I am trying to remove these from the code but when I check the value of `e.Row.Cells[index].Text` it doesn't contain `<br/>` and is has `;br/&gt;` instead.

So I tried creating a function that removes any substring starting with `<` and ending with `>` or starting with `&` and ending with `;`. The code removes the `<>` but it is still showing `br/`

Code:

```
index = gv.Columns.HeaderIndex("Message");
if (index > 0)
{
   string message = RemoveHTMLMarkup(e.Row.Cells[index].Text);
   e.Row.Cells[index].Text = message;
}

static string RemoveHTMLMarkup(string text)
{
        return Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(text, "<.+?>", string.Empty), "&.+?;", string.Empty);
}
```

How do I remove the `<br/>` tag?

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2307070) about why ṫ̨̗̺̭̮̞̗̜̮̗̙̫̺̖̭̯͊ͨ̌͒̍͘͘͟͝h̸͓̩̙͙̻̗͔̞̘̟̩̯͋͑͂͐a̴̧ͨ́ͭ͒ͯ̓͐̇̃ͥ͢҉‌​̨̳̜̤͍͖t̵̳̳͕͉͋̓͐ͦͬ̈́̀̚‌ is a bad idea. Also, are you sure it's `;br/&gt;` and not  `&lt;br/&gt;`?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub yes you are right it is `&lt;br/&gt;`. So if I don't use regex then what should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a literal string, you (sh|c)ould only use `String.Replace()`:

```
static string RemoveHTMLNewLines(string text)
{
    return text.Replace("&lt;br/&gt;", string.Empty);
}
```

Or replace with `Environment.NewLine` if needed.

Answer (score 2):

1. De-entitize the string.
2. Then use regex to to find and remove expected tags.

Or

If you have enough time to study and Use, then use **HtmlAgilityPack** package.

[About HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

[Nuget Package Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/)

Answer (score 1):

Being regardless of the question, I am curious about what this is:

[image]